# Does the user have access to the function definitions of my webpage's javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Let's assume i have created a simple game, which uses several functions, and is not multiplayer. Is it possible to access the function definitions that i wrote, from within the browser?

Also let's say, for instance, there is a function that has a `score` parameter and sends a "you win" message to the user if his score reaches a certain number. Is it possible to call that function through the console with arguments specified by the user?

If any of the above are possible, then how can i try them?

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: @Brian I would, but i am not sure how.

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: have you even written any JS code so far?

Comment: Javascript is client side which means everybody can access the code source

Comment: @Brian In what regard?? Yes, i have, but i assume you are referring to the complexity of it, in which case i've only written simple code.

Comment: write a file with this content: `function saySomething(argument){console.log(argument);}` and type saySomething("something") in the console. that's how simple it is

Comment: @Brian What i meant to say (and i am sorry if i phrased it incorrectly)  is if i can call the functions without knowing their name/functionality. If i let a friend play the game on my computer (he has no knowledge of the code) will he be able to find the function names, what they do, and call them so that he can (e.g.) win?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Cheating on Javascript Game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171101/prevent-cheating-on-javascript-game)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to access the function definitions that i wrote, from within the browser?

Yes.

> let's say, for instance, there is a function that has a score parameter and sends a "you win" message to the user if his score reaches a certain number. Is it possible to call that function through the console with arguments specified by the user?

Yes.

> If any of the above are possible, then how can i try them?

If the function is a global, just type the name of it.

If it isn't a global, then set a breakpoint somewhere in a scope that has access to that function, do whatever it takes to trigger that breakpoint, then it is as above.

Related: [Prevent Cheating on Javascript Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171101/prevent-cheating-on-javascript-game) and [What good ways are there to prevent cheating in JavaScript multiplayer games?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250403/what-good-ways-are-there-to-prevent-cheating-in-javascript-multiplayer-games).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the references, they will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. 
The question is, how you wrote your code.

If you wrote it like this:

```
(function(module, window, document, undefined){
    module.public = function(){
        //code here
    }
    function private(){
        //code here
    }
}((window.play = {}), window, document);
```

You can access the score function with `(window.)play.public();` the window. is not necessary. The function `private`could not be accessed outsite the `module function`.

If your code likes this:

```
function public(){
    //code here
}
function private(){
    //code here
}
```

Both functions are availalbe with `public(); private();`.

How to access your code:

1. Open the developer tools of the browser.
2. Open the tab "sources"
3. Navigate to the script
4. Look up all the written code
5. Set breakpoints to modify the data, when a function is called
6. ...

How to secure your code:

- You can uglify / minify your code https://jscompress.com/
- Use a backend for functionality (for a little game it is way overpowered)
- Google for JavaScript Security Methods